# Prepare PDO insert wrongly backslash

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have troubles when I use "PDO prepare" :

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO table (id, reponse_id_num_quest  , reponse__rep, reponse__commentaire) VALUES (:id, :id_quest, :val, :comm)";
$res=$db->prepare($sql);
$res->bindParam(':id',$idUniq);
$res->bindParam(':id_quest',$ids[$index]);
$res->bindParam(':val',$val);
$res->bindParam(':comm',$commentaire, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res->execute();
```

When the variable "$commentaire" contains a string with quote " ' " or backslash, the query insert backslash before the special character.

> Ex:
>
> Original string : I don't
>
> In base string : I don\'t

So, on the final HTML view, the string isn't the original.

How could I insert correctly ? Thanks

Comment: Find out where the slashes are coming from. As in: debug your code and environment.

Comment: I have fixed it.

I  have create an .htaccess with this content : php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off